# Hibernate Envers save Username just using servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, hibernate-envers

I have a project where i use Hibernate and i wanna use Envers for logging, but i need the username of who is making the changes because a incorrect configuration can lead to financial problems so the cliente wanna know who did it.

The project use Java EE but just with servets, there is anyway to get the user from a session while envers is saving the audited entity?

The logged user stay in a session, so i need to retrieve it from there or save in another place use another strategy i don't know.

I searched alot but just found solution when using Frameworks like spring, vraptor etc

I need a solution without framework because i can't port the project to this framework, at least not now.

Thx in advance!

Comment: I cannot get why you don't want to use session for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to set the session using a filter in a `ThreadLocal` when the request starts, and unset it when the request completes.

You can then use the `RevisionListener` to get the session from the thread local and set the username on a custom revision entity.

Comment: It does, worked! I never used ThreadLocal before, i read somewhere that using it in a JEE environment can cause problems and i need to remove it after using a thread local, do you know any other problems that using ThreadLocal can cause?
Thx!

Comment: It's good practice to clear `ThreadLocal`s after the request completes (e.g. in a filter, after all other processing), but otherwise should be safe to use.